# Java Json десериализация только нужных данных

Tags: java, json, jackson, десериализация

Java Json десериализация только нужных данных
Как содержимое которое находится в «Campaigns» положить как объект в массив?
Желательно при помощи библиотеки jackson

Json строка

```
{
  "result": {
    "Campaigns": [
      {
        "Id": 37272735,
        "StartDate": "2018-09-14",
        "Name": "Optliner v1"
      },
      {
        "Name": "MyTestCompany",
        "StartDate": "2019-06-09",
        "Id": 43840339
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Объект

```
public class MyClass {

    int id;
    String startDate;
    String name;

    // geters and setters

}
```

Мой код который не работает

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"result\": {\n" +
                "    \"Campaigns\": [\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "        \"id\": 37272735,\n" +
                "        \"startDate\": \"2018-09-14\",\n" +
                "        \"name\": \"Optliner v1\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "        \"name\": \"MyTestCompany\",\n" +
                "        \"startDate\": \"2019-06-09\",\n" +
                "        \"id\": 43840339\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<MyClass> myObjects = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, MyClass[].class));
        for (MyClass el : myObjects) {
            System.out.println(el.getName() + " " + el.getStartDate() + " " + el.getId());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы заработало нужно использовать объект с идентичной структурой.

Попробуйте

```
class Wrapper {
    Result result;
}
class Result {
    List<MyClass> Campaigns;
}

mapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class).getResult().getCompains().stream().foreach(el -> {
            System.out.println(el.getName() + " " + el.getStartDate() + " " + el.getId());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

можно подключить

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

создать объект конфигурацию для сериализации

```
    private static Configuration gsonConf = Configuration
            .builder()
            .jsonProvider(new GsonJsonProvider())
            .mappingProvider(new GsonMappingProvider())
            .build();
```

передать json в виде строки, указать к какому классу сериализовать, путь до нужного нам json структуры

```
 private static <T> T getObject(String json, Class<T> objectClass, String jsonPath) {
        return JsonPath.using(gsonConf).parse(json).read(jsonPath, objectClass);
    }
```

это пример как получить списком

```
    private static <T> List<T> getObjectsList(String json, Class<T[]> objectClass, String jsonPath) {
        return Arrays.asList(getObject(json, objectClass, jsonPath));
    }
```

и вызывать в Вашем случае как

```
    List<MyClass> objectsList = getObjectsList(json, MyClass[].class, "$.result.Campaigns");
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, решение задачи такое

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json).get("result").get("Campaigns");
        List<MyClass> myObjects = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(node.toString(), MyClass[].class));
        for (MyClass el : myObjects) {
            System.out.println(el.getName() + " " + el.getStartDate() + " " + el.getId());
        }
```